# ImageMagick Mogrify: batch with watermark

Tags: imagemagick, mogrify

I have a strange problem with running ImageMagick mogrify on several files. I use conversion string to make several transformation on images, which results in thumbnails. The command with the conversion string runs fine on single file, however when ran on a batch of files, it sometimes fails. Here is the command (windows command line):

```
"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.3.5-Q16\mogrify" \
  -format jpg \
  -thumbnail 400x400">" \
  -background white \
  -gravity center \
  -extent 400x400 \
  -draw "image src-over 0,0 0,0 '//dell1/Oracle/files/watermark.png'" \
  -path \\dell1\Oracle\files\pictures\cj4uoveomiggda97kmqttn0400 \
        \\dell1\Oracle\files\pictures\59\59p5huflk2cnv9drf3r1d65ef9_wc \
        \\dell1\Oracle\files\pictures\7v\7vi3q26cdidk8bproslhhmlkab_wc \
        \\dell1\Oracle\files\pictures\ft\ft0iqkjk08cli8k0iltgmdmfo5_wc
```

and it fails with message

> mogrify: Non-conforming drawing primitive definition `image'

But I've found out, that this happens only when inserting a watermark. I've also found out that when I change order of the 3 files which are to be processed, the mogrify runs fine, which is pretty strange. I have no idea why this happens and how to get rid of it.

PS: I execute this command from a java application, so using a batch file with repeated calling of **convert** command is not acceptable solution for me.

Any clues appreciated, many thanks.

Comment: Solved this by installing newer version of ImageMagick :/

Comment: Please add this comment as an answer. (You can even upvote and accept it and harvest your bonus points...)   :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by installing newer version of ImageMagick :/